# How to make footer stick on asp.net page?

Tags: css, asp.net, master-pages, sticky-footer

I have a master page in asp.net which will contain other pages content throw a ContentPlaceHolder. I want to have a footer in the master page that sticks at the bottom usin css not matter what is displayed in the pages the uses the content ContentPlaceHolder.

Here is my master page:

```
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%;">
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="True">
    <Scripts>
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery-1.11.2.min.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/CommonMethods.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/CommonProperties.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js" />
        <asp:ScriptReference Path="Scripts/jquery.watermark.min.js" />
    </Scripts>
</asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="header">
    <h1>
        SABIS® Educational Systems INC.
    </h1>
</div>
<div id="nav">
</div>
<div id="section">
    <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    Copyright © Sabis.net
</div>
<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="cpClientScript" runat="server">
</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
</form>
```

I tried lots of css but nothing works properly for me there is always a flow!!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, I think you're mixing some things up so first: ASP has no impact on the way browsers display your page. That's because ASP is a server-side language that outputs pure HTML. This HTML is then sent to your browser, along with any assets that are linked to (CSS, JavaScript, images...).

So that's where the CSS comes in. CSS is used to add styling to HTML. So you're absolutely right that CSS is the way to get the behavior that you described. Here's how:

```
div#footer{ // Add the style below to the div with ID "footer"
    position: fixed; // Set the position to "fixed" to the screen
    bottom: 0px; // The fixed position should be 0px from the bottom of the screen
    width: 100%; // Optional, this stretches the div across the width of the screen
}
```

You can either put this piece of CSS in a `<style>` tag in the `<head>` of your page, but it's usually better to put it in a separate .css file and link to it in the `<head>` of the page, like so:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="path/to/stylesheet.css">
```

Additional reading: [here's a getting started guide about CSS stylesheets.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Getting_started)

Comment: Thanks for this awesome introduction. I do know what you said, but may be I didn't explain myself well, still this is my first experience with web. Any way the css you supplied worked just as I want it.  Thank you.